# is there a way to create a number of variables like x1, x2, etc., where I can vary the number of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I am trying to create a number of variables that I can use based on the input to a function
function(n), so I have n variables, all titled x1, x2,...,xn. As well, could I call the variables with like a loop with something almost like

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(xi)
```

this is what I tried

```
def createVar(n):
    var='x'+str(n)
    Vars=globals()
    Vars[var]=0
```

Comment: Consider using a `list` or `dict` instead. A variable number of named variables can be problematic because whatever uses these variables later would have to know their names. You may just be creating more problems for yourself down the road.

Comment: `createVar` worked. Is the for loop the problem? You could get them from `globals()` just like you set them.

Comment: Your loop cannot print the values of global variables created by your function - it will just look for a variable named `xi`. This is all a minefield of potential confusion - it;s good advice as already commented to use an alternative data structure.